# How do I correctly inherit templates in flask that use bootstrap?

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flask

It seems if I use `{% extends "base.html" %}` it inherits the template correctly but the navbar doesn't use bootstrap.

If I use `{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}` it doesn't even work. I don't get errors but it just sets the title to Index and then the page is blank.

Another note: The only way I've gotten the navbar to show up is directly putting it inside `index.html` and using `{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}`

I am using *Flask Web Development by Miguel Grinberg* and the code is identical except the obvious content.

What am I doing wrong? And does anyone have good resources for slowly jumping into Flask that doesn't just dive in head first? I'm having trouble understanding the little nitpicky details.

**base.html:**

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
<html>

<head>
    {% block head %}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - MyFlask</title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>

    {% block navbar %}
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Navbar</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyFlask</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/bootstrap"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
        <div class="container">
            {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

**index.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    <h3>Session info:</h3>
    <p><b>Browser:</b> {{ browser }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the template inheritance it is common to define the structure of the layout in the base template, and then provide the specific details of each child template in the blocks (like `content`, `page_content`, etc).

In the above example where the `base` template itself is a child template (of "bootstrap/base.html"), the same pattern can be used.

Instead of defining HTML tags (like `<html>`, `<head>`, etc.) it's better to use the corresponding *blocks*. Flask bootstrap [defines](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html) such blocks corresponding to each of these HTML tags, where child templates can override.

So if you change the `base.html` template as follows, then the `index` template can use the layout defined in `bootstrap/base`:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block head %}
    {{ super() }}
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - MyFlask</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Navbar</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyFlask</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/bootstrap"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Note that in the `head` block, we are using `super()` to bring whatever Flask bootstrap has defined in the `head` block (could be loading CSS, JS files, etc.). This allows the `base.html` template to customize the `head` section. However if you do not require this control and only want to specify the title of the page, then you can avoid overwriting `head` block and just define the `title` block. To do this change `base.html` file to start like:

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% block page_name %}{% endblock %} - MyFlask{% endblock %}
```

Removing `{% block head %} ...` section.
And then modify your `index.html` template to define the `page_name` block instead of `title`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_name %}Index{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    <h3>Session info:</h3>
    <p><b>Browser:</b> {{ browser }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now the title of the index page will be "Index - MyFlask", so you could have a common suffix for the title of all the pages.

Or if you need each page to have their own specific title, you may define the `title` block in there, overriding the `title` block in `base.html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are a life saver. Just one question, it show <title> tag twice. Is that common or it should show only one title tag?

Comment: It should be because of using both the HTML tag `<title>` and the block `{% block title %}` in the head block. Possibly just using the `{% block title %}` is the better approach.